# Sending emails using mailCore2 giving error code = 30

Tags: swift, email, mailcore2

I am using MailCore2 framework to send emails. I am not using MFMailComposer because the requirement
is not to have any UI for email. We just getting email id and on click of button sending some information
to email address.
This is my code mentioned below

```
 func sendEmailToCustomer(emailid:String?)
    {
        let session : MCOSMTPSession = MCOSMTPSession()
        session.hostname = "mail.***.com"
        session.port = 25
        session.connectionType = MCOConnectionType.clear

        let builder = MCOMessageBuilder()
        builder.header.from = MCOAddress(displayName: " iPad App", mailbox:"INVESTOR@xxx.com")
        builder.header.to = [MCOAddress(displayName: "iPad App", mailbox:emailid)]

        builder.header.subject = "Email Link   \(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("branch_id")!)"
        builder.htmlBody = "Thanks for choosing . Here is link you wanted to have in your inbox \n  \((webView.request?.URL?.absoluteString)!))"
        let data = builder.data()

        let sendOperation : MCOSMTPSendOperation = session.sendOperationWithData(data)
        NSUserDefaults .standardUserDefaults().setValue(emailid, forKey: "Customer_EmailId")
        sendOperation.start({
            (error : NSError?) -> Void in

            if(error != nil){
                //Keep sending the email till it succeeds.  needs to know for security reasons.
               // self.sendEmailToCustomer(emailid)
                print("customer email failed.\(error?.code) \(error)")
                self.showAlertMessage(MESSAGE_EMAIL_Not_SENT, title:"Email Not Sent", actions: [UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) {action in
                    }], withSound: false)
                Crittercism.leaveBreadcrumb("customer email failed")
            }
            else{
                //Email sent successfully.

                print("Email sent successfully \(emailid)")
                self.showAlertMessage(MESSAGE_EMAIL_SENT, title:"Email Sent", actions: [UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) {action in
                    }], withSound: false)

            }
        })
    }
```

When my "to" email is with in organization, its working fine. But if i try to send email to some outside
account, then getting error 'Error Domain=MCOErrorDomain Code=30 '
I tried changing different Ports ,connection type . Nothing is working. Please help

Comment: Can you use the connectionLogger to figure out the exact error message that the server sends?

Comment: Connectionlogger: 550 5.0.0 550 Denied for External Relay: nfghdhdhd8@gmail.com

Comment: This is error message which i am getting in connection logger

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not related to mailcore2, but rather to the mailserver you are using. The error message you are getting '550 Denied for External Relay' means that the mail server you are connecting to is not configured to allow you to send to other domains. 
Talk to the postmaster of that smtp server if you believe that configuration to be in error. (postmaster@, insert the domain of the server instead of  )